# Open a file with user input Ruby

Tags: ruby, file-io

I take a string variable from a user like this:

```
mail = gets
```

and I want to use this variable to open a file.

```
file = File.new(mail, "r") ##obviously this isn't working
```

How do I actually use this mail variable to open a file of that name?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mail = gets.chomp
```

gets function gives a string with \n in the end.

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thanks texasbruce

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `mail = gets.strip`.

`strip` seems to be **slightly** slower than `chomp` but I find it to be a little bit more readable.

If you're curious about the benchmark, check out the gist [here](https://gist.github.com/3984074).